# How to forget a network for good programmatically

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager

I have an app that connects to a WiFi network. In the end, it is supposed to remove the network, and it does: if you go to the phone's WiFi settings and click the network that the app removed, it asks you for the password.

The problem comes when I restart the phone. On restart, it connects to the supposedly forgotten network. I have no idea how or why this is happening.

I've tried:

```
wifiManager.disableNetwork(networkId);
wifiManager.removeNetwork(networkId);
wifiManager.disconnect();
```

Comment: looks like a firmware (or even Android) bug for me